# Why is my binary much smaller than my object file?

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker, elf

I'm using GCC 4.7 to compile a large app that consists of only one C++ source file, so there's only one compilation unit, but it includes many long headers. The final optimized executable, myapp, is 40MB, but the optimized object file, myapp.o, is 101MB. How is it possible that the object file is bigger than the binary?

I ran "nm -AC myapp" and "nm -AC myapp.o" to see if one had dramatically more symbols than the other -- there's about 1000 symbols difference but they're mostly things you would expect like the binary adding the symbols for standard exception handling and static init.

I then ran 'readelf -a' on both and got this for myapp.o:

```
Number of section headers:         29186
Section header string table index: 29183
```

But this for myapp:

```
Number of section headers:         40
Section header string table index: 37
```

So I'm guessing that accounts for the size difference, but I don't actually know what this means, or how to get the size down. Am I barking up the wrong tree? My goal is to get the compile time for myapp down, but first I need to understand what's wrong. If symbols were the problem I could look into using  GCC's -fvisibility=hidden option, but I'd expect more differences in nm if that were the problem.

Edit: Additional info, everything not defined in my source file is from dynamically linked libs.

Comment: A look at sections name does not give any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object files contain lots of extra info to allow the seperate files to be linked together. In addition much code may be optimized out once all object files in the project are linked together. (example, uncalled library routines may be included in the object file, but are not needed once the compiler knows which routines wil actually be used in the final binary.

Comment: I don't think uncalled routines matter here since there's only one object file. If the routine isn't called, either it's inline and code for it shouldn't be generated, or it's not inline in which case it won't be in the object file. Everything myapp is linking it's dynamic linking, so the only way to get in the final binary should be by being in the object file, as far as I understand.

Comment: how do you propose that the compiler determain that the linker will be told to use only one object file?

Comment: I wasn't expecting the linker to be told, I was expecting the compiler to generate code only for inline functions when called. I forgot though that for C/C++ this is not true (the compiler always generates a non-inline version in case the address of it is taken by something outside the library).

Comment: I'm not sure if your really answer his question. For start, he does not mention about using link time optimization. The OP's example show a huge difference between the number of sections in the binary and *one* object code. In fact, executable files does not need have sections, but program segments. I think you need to elaborate better your answer.